# UWP application and .NET Core RC2: cannot reference netstandard1.4 packages

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, dnx, windows-10-iot-core

I have a scenario where I run a UWP client application, a UWP IOT application and a .NET Core application using a shared code base.
In .NET Core RC1 I built a Class Library (Package) and used "dotnet5.4" as the base framework for that library.

Using "generate build output" I could reference the created nuget packages from the .NET Core application (console) and using a workaround (copy the packages from %local%.dnx -> %local%.nuget) the UWP applications were able to reference and use the package as well.

Now in RC2 things have changed a bit and I am again able to consume the upgraded library (tooling upgraded in project file, changes to project.json, netstandard1.4 (since 1.5 does not work with UAP10 according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md))) perfectly using the .NET Core console application.

For UWP I cannot add the library since I get dozens of infamous

```
"[...] provides a compile-time reference assembly [...] but there is no run-time assembly compatible with [...]"
```

errors.

After some looking around, I tried to isolate the issue and found out that I can't even add a reference to System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher due to:

```
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86.
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
```

I have a minimal solution to reproduce the issue uploaded [to OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1DDFA1793BD83CB5!355608&authkey=!ACQVm7qC9bFwaTw&ithint=file%2Czip).

I made no changes to the blank UWP template except for the dependencies in project.json:

```
"dependencies":
{
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel": "2.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",

    "System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher": "4.0.0-rc2-24027"
},
```

Note: I updated Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to the latest version. I added NETStandard.Library and Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.

Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance
-Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher isn't currently supported in UWP.  The modern SDK doesn't expose the underlying windows API (ReadDirectoryChanges) that we need to implement it.

-Eric, .NET team