# Could not load file or assembly using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on a windows 10 IoT project where I want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json so I added it in my project.json in the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
"System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1",
"System.Xml.XPath.XDocument": "4.0.1",
"Serilog": "2.2.1",
"Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.2.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0"
},
```

I can deploy my solution but I have this exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher,     
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

I tried adding System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher to my dependencies in project.json but it didn't solve the problem...

It looks like this person has a similar problem:
[UWP application and .NET Core RC2: cannot reference netstandard1.4 packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365216/uwp-application-and-net-core-rc2-cannot-reference-netstandard1-4-packages)

Somebody has an idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" is not supported by UWP project yet. As the error message shows,

```
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
```

If your purpose is to retreive the connectionString from your ASP.NET config file, you can use some other NuGet packages to do the trick, **"NewtonSoft.Json"** is a popular one among them. It shouldn't be hard to do it though, just load the config file and parse the json format.

Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tryed implementing a configuration manager using **NewtonSoft.Json** But when I try to open the file, I Have an `Acces denied`. I Don't understand why as my file is in a folder I am suppose to be able to open `C:\\Data\\Users\\DefaultAccount\\AppData\\Local\\DevelopmentFiles\\PackageName\\config.json`  Do you have an idea?